# R knitr chunk results prompt with "FALSE"

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have a chunk such like:

```
<<echo=T,comment=F,warning=FALSE,cache=FALSE,error=FALSE,message=FALSE,prompt=FALSE>>=
rm("new")
print(summary(glmer(rotams~log(epidays)+daysbirth+rotaarm+gender+epiexlbf+(1|sid),data=rtf2,family=binomial)))
@
```

which shows a result in PDF like:

[image]

## Question1:

How to get rid of the prompt "FALSE"

## Question2:

How to move "(1 | sid)" to the next line? it's out of page width.

Comment: #1: maybe `prompt=""` ?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41471/getting-sweave-code-chunks-to-stay-inside-page-margins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your first question,you specified that you want `comment=F` which changes the comment characters to `FALSE`. Just remove this option or set it to `comment=""`.

About your second question, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Hope it helps,

alex